# Character set used by ISO8583 version 1993

Tags: java, iso8583, iso8583-1993

What is the character set used by iso8583 version 1993. Currently we tried with ISO-8859-1 and its not working.
With Character set(ISO-8859-1) I am able to read the massage but when I try to send response it is not working.

Do I need to set any specific header type in xml file to send ISO8583 1993 request like I set for normal ISO massage as follows :

```
<header type="0800">ISO015000015</header>
<header type="0810">ISO015000015</header>
<header type="0100">ISO015000050</header>
<header type="0110">ISO015000055</header>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iso8583 message encoding and decoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541185/iso8583-message-encoding-and-decoding). Also seems off-topic same as the dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO 8583 doesn't define character sets. Every field is serialized according to some rule defined in your specific variant of ISO 8583, some of those fields may be string encodings, but others may contain binary or bcd data, etc. You need to refer to your specific variant of ISO 8583 to find out how it handles encodings of which fields.